# VIDEO IO Error : V4L : can't open camera by index 0

Tags: opencv, digital-ocean

I have been developing a web application that makes use of my Laptop's inbuilt webcam using openCV. It is working fine in the local host. But when I hosted it (I chose Digital Ocean cloud - a Linux server), the following error shows up:

VIDEOIO ERROR : V4L : can't open camera by index 0

Though 0 is the index to open the default camera, I've tried with -1,1,2 but none of them worked.
I've also made sure to install all the python libraries that the application requires.

```py
class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()
```

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: You are trying to access a camera where the app is running... in your case digital ocean, which i doubt they have a camera connected for you to access..

Comment: Is there a way to check to make the camera function? What could be the other alternatives if webcam can't be accessed?